# Module 500 error in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I'm moving a website made in Symfony from `abc.com` to `xyz.com`. Issue I'm facing is I'm getting a 500 error once I try to login. Code has not a bit changed between these two sites.

After a lot of debugging, I came to know a request is being sent to `xxx.com\login\login`. Now the issue is `abc.com\login\login` is working okay however `xyz.com\login\login` is throwing 500 error.

This seems to be a routing issue but I'm now not able to see exactly where the problem is because I have not made any changes to anything & this is giving me nuts.

Can anybody help in resolving this issue? Sorry I'm new to Symfony.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figuring out why 500 errors occur in your production environment can be difficult, and there can be many reasons why they might occur. For example, have you forgotten to comment out `dump` in your twig files.

I would suggest appending the debug URL to you links and use the DEV environment to troubleshoot. The debug URL is `app_dev.php`, and for the above URL you've indicated you would use:

```
xyz.com/app_dev.php/login/login
```

I presume that is what you are typing into your browser (the forward slashes I mean)? You will have to edit your `app_dev.php` file (in the `web` folder) to add the remote IP address of your browser by modifying the `REMOTE_ADDR` array (open that file and you'll see what I mean).

Also check your `var/logs/dev.log` log file for information, this is a good place to start.

Comment: This has really helped me, thanks a ton. Error resolved.